# How to query and execute trigger on the same table

Tags: oracle, triggers

Hope someone can help with this. I am new to triggers and I am trying to create a trigger that checks to see if the record being modified has a specific value.

example
I have a table called Filing that has a filing_id and a filing_status, I want to prevent someone from updating or deleting any records in that table has a filing_status="FILED".
so if i have the following

```
Filing_id    Filing_status    Val
---------    -------------    ---
0             Filed           X
```

If someone tried to modify Val the trigger should stop it
I have created the following trigger:

```
CREATE or replace TRIGGER TRG_PREV_FILING
  BEFORE DELETE or UPDATE
  ON PF.FILING
  FOR EACH ROW
   declare
     rowcnt number;
   BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(filing_id) INTO rowcnt FROM PF.FILING 
      where status = 'FILED'
       and  filing_id = :new.filing_id;
     if (rowcnt > 0)
     then
      raise_application_error (-20100, 'You can not delete Or Update initial record');
     end if;
   END;
```

The problem I am facing is I am getting:ORA-04091 which is "Table Filing is mutating, Trigger/function may not see it"

So basically I can't query on the same table that I am executing the trigger on? Is that the problem in my case and does anyone know a work around this?

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to query the table trigger is firing on to be able to do that kind of check. You can get value of a column that is being modified using `:old`. Here is an example:

```
SQL> create table filing(
  2    status varchar2(31),
  3    val    number
  4  );

Table created


SQL> create or replace trigger TRG_FILING before delete or update on FILING
  2  for each row
  3  begin
  4    if lower(:old.status) = 'filed'
  5    then
  6      raise_application_error(-20000, 'You cannot delete or modify this record');
  7    end if;
  8  end;

SQL> /

Trigger created


SQL> insert into FILING values('FILED', null);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into filing values('OK', 1);

1 row inserted

SQL> commit;

Commit complete

SQL> select *
  2    from filing;

STATUS                                 VAL
------------------------------- ----------
FILED                           
OK                                       1 

SQL> delete
  2    from filing
  3   where val is null;


ORA-20000: You cannot delete or modify this record
ORA-06512: at "HR.TRG_FILING", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'HR.TRG_FILING'
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic point is that you should design you database in a way that the trigger does its validation based on the updated/deleted row. If you have several rows with the same `filing_id` then you can overwork you database design. Maybe you really only check against the own table in which case you can use `:old`. But when you have several rows to check (which I assume because you make a count) then you have to use two tables. Here is a suggestion.

```
create table filing_status (filing_id number, status varchar2(10));
create table filing_content (filing_id number, content_id number, content varchar2(200));
CREATE or replace TRIGGER TRG_PREV_FILING
  BEFORE DELETE or UPDATE
  ON FILING_content
  FOR EACH ROW
   declare
     rowcnt number;
   BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(filing_id) INTO rowcnt FROM FILING_status 
      where status = 'FILED'
       and  filing_id = :new.filing_id;
     if (rowcnt > 0)
     then
      raise_application_error (-20100, 'You can not delete Or update filed record');
     end if;
   END;
/
insert into filing_status values (1, 'FILING');
insert into filing_content values (1, 1, 'foo');
insert into filing_content values (1, 2, 'bar');
insert into filing_status values (1, 'FILED');
update filing_content set content = 'bahr' where filing_id = 1 and content_id = 2;

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20100: You can not delete Or update filed record
ORA-06512: at "DEMO.TRG_PREV_FILING", line 9
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'DEMO.TRG_PREV_FILING'
```